# FragmentManager not calling onCreateView with second tab after orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have 3 fragments in TabA, and a PreferenceFragment in TabB.  To recreate the problem I start the program, TabA displays fine.  I click TabB and it also displays fine.  If I return to TabA, and do an orientation change, the next time I click on TabB there is just a blank screen.  I've narrowed it down to the FragmentManager not calling onCreateView on the Fragment in TabB.

I'm checking that the Fragments are not null and don't need to be recreated and getting references to them with their findFragmentByTag after orientation changes.  TabA never has an issue, i tried to recreate the issue with TabA but onCreateView would always get called by the FragmentManager for each Fragment.  I have min API 15, target 19.

Pruned down version of MyActivity.java to be runnable

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    public FragmentManager fm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_master);

        fm = getFragmentManager();

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ActionBar.Tab tabA = actionBar.newTab().setText("Main");
        ActionBar.Tab tabB = actionBar.newTab().setText("Settings");

        tabA.setTabListener(new TabAListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(tabA);

        tabB.setTabListener(new TabBListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(tabB);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            int index = savedInstanceState.getInt("index");
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(index);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        int i = getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex();
        outState.putInt("index", i);
    }

    public class TabAListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

        private static final String genTag = "GenerateFragment";
        private static final String aboutTag = "AboutFragment";
        public static final String resultsTag = "ResultsListFragment";

        private ArrayList<Fragment> fragList;

        public TabAListener(Activity activity) {
            fragList = null;
        }

        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // Reselected don't do anything
            Log.d(TAG, "Tab A: on Tab reselected");
        }

        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Tab A: on Tab Selected");

            // attach all the fragments
            if (fragList == null) {
                fragList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

                TestFragment genFrag;
                if (fm.findFragmentByTag(genTag) == null) {
                    genFrag = new TestFragment();
                    ft.add(R.id.gen_fragment, genFrag, genTag);
                } else genFrag = (TestFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(genTag);
                TestFragment aboutFrag;
                if (fm.findFragmentByTag(aboutTag) == null) {
                    aboutFrag = new TestFragment();
                    ft.add(R.id.about_fragment, aboutFrag, aboutTag);
                } else aboutFrag = (TestFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(aboutTag);
                TestFragment resultsFrag;
                if (fm.findFragmentByTag(resultsTag) == null) {
                    resultsFrag = new TestFragment();
                    ft.add(R.id.results_fragment, resultsFrag, resultsTag);
                } else {
                    resultsFrag = (TestFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(resultsTag);
                }


                fragList.add(genFrag);
                fragList.add(aboutFrag);
                fragList.add(resultsFrag);
                Log.d(TAG, "Tab A: Added fragments to the ArrayList");

            } else {

                Iterator iter = fragList.iterator();

                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Tab A: Attaching fragments");
                    ft.attach((Fragment) iter.next());
                }
            }
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Tab A: on Tab Unselected");

            if (fragList != null) {
                Iterator iter = fragList.iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Tab A: Fragments detached");
                    ft.detach((Fragment) iter.next());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class TabBListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

        private static final String settingsTag = "SettingsFragment";

        private ArrayList<Fragment> fragList;

        public TabBListener(Activity activity) {
            fragList = null;
        }

        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // Reselected don't do anything
            Log.d(TAG, "Tab B: on Tab reselected");
        }

        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Tab B: on Tab Selected");
            // attach all the fragments
            if (fragList == null) {

                fragList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
                TestFragment settingsFrag;
                if (fm.findFragmentByTag(settingsTag) == null) {
                    settingsFrag = new TestFragment();
                    ft.add(R.id.frame_main, settingsFrag, settingsTag);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Tab B: not null");
                    settingsFrag = (TestFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(settingsTag);
                }

                fragList.add(settingsFrag);
                Log.d(TAG, "Tab B: Added fragments to the ArrayList");

            } else {

                Iterator iter = fragList.iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Tab B: Attaching fragments");
                    ft.attach((Fragment) iter.next());
                }
            }
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Tab B: on Tab Unselected");

            if (fragList != null) {
                Iterator iter = fragList.iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Tab B: Fragments detached");
                    ft.detach((Fragment) iter.next());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class TestFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setRetainInstance(true);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text, container, false);
        }
    }

}
```

activity_master.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frame_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/gen_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/about_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/results_fragment"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

fragment_text.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I guess I have to remove the super call in MainActivity.onSaveInstanceState in order for onCreateView to be called correctly for TabB's fragment after an orientation change.  Umm, I'm not sure why that works so could someone explain why?

I've been able to gather that the super.onSaveInstanceState saves the activities views for when the user navigates away from the application and eventually returns.  And the FragmentManager also has responsibility for the contents of the fragment through orientation changes.  I'm kind of lost at that point.